# Cancel StreamSubscription from Inside its Callback

Tags: dart, dart-async

Here is a ***(simplified)* scenario** of the situation:

```
stream.listen((bool result) {
  if (result) {
    // should cancel the subscription
  }
});
```

I want to *stop listening* to a `Stream` based on its content, but I cannot wrap my head about it enough to come to a conclusion.

```
StreamSubscription streamSubscription = stream.listen((_) {});

streamSubscription.cancel(); // cancels the subscription
```

With `cancel()` I can normally cancel my subscription, but I cannot access `streamSubscription` in the `listen` callback.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to split variable declaration and initialization:

```
StreamSubscription streamSubscription;
streamSubscription = stream.listen((bool result) {
  if (result) {
    streamSubscription.cancel();
  }
});
```

Comment: I knew I had done it before! I solved my problem with `StreamIterator`, but I do not think that it generally fits as an answer to my simplified question :)

Comment: You can't solve the simplified scenario because there is no reference to the `StreamSubscription` anywhere, so you can't cancel it. You need to store a reference to the subscription, and you need to do that in a variable that isn't being declared on the line where you refer to it, so the code in this answer is actually the shortest solution to your simplified scenario.

Answer (score 0):

With Dart version >= 2.12 that introduces [null safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety):

```dart
StreamSubscription? s;
s = controller.stream.listen(
  (val) {
    print(val);
    if (val == "someVal") {
      s?.cancel();
    }
  },
  onError: (e) => print("onError"),
  // This will be called on stream closed event 
  // ONLY IF the subscription is still active
  onDone: () { print("onDone"); }
);
```